# Get next alarm on pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Since Android SDK 21 (Lollipop) we are able to fetch the next upcoming alarm set by the user with following code:

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
AlarmClockInfo alarmInfo = manager.getNextAlarmClock();
```

It is also possible to listen for alarm changes with [ACTION_NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ACTION_NEXT_ALARM_CLOCK_CHANGED) broadcast (also 21+). Is there something similar I could use on pre Lollipop devices? It would be enough for me if the solution works for all 18+ devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pre Lollipop SDK you can only get

> A formatted string of the next alarm that is set, or the empty string if there is no alarm set.

For that, you can use the next snippet

```
String nextAlarm = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
```